# Programmatically (C#) determine if (in a Win 7 box) the local audit policy "Audit account logon events" is set to "No auditing, Success, or Failure"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to programmatically determine if Local Security Policy setting for "Audit account logon events" has any setting, and if it has been set if it is Success or Failure.

I'm trying to create a win-service that'll help in monitoring the hardness of the OS.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat difficult issue, since no real managed API exists for doing this. This link highlights some options others have used.    http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f3f5a61f-2ab9-459e-a1ee-c187465198e0

Comment: While not the same thing, that link has helped a great deal in narrowing down my search and addressing very wide sweeping methods to maybe get my ideal values programmatically. Methinks it may be more plausible then to visit registry keys and then do analysis on them to determine settings? Thoughts/Opinions? 

Overall thanks for the link/help!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after reading the above link. I dug around in the registry for a bit but couldn't seem to find where your particular setting is stored. If you were to find it, it would be as easy as reading the value, and re-assigning it if it was wrong.